# How to make Live Dashboard using Asp.Net

Tags: ajax, web-services, dashboard, live

I want to know how to make a live dashboard using Asp.Net (client server architecture). Do I have to call web service through Ajax every 5s time to check updates? Or is there any other technology to rather than calling a web service recently, because calling web service tends to increase server load.

Comment: You should try to write some codes and paste here , we will solve your code issues.

Comment: i don't have code issue, i'm asking a what was the better way to do that kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

In your client you should use JavaScript for updates. You can use AJAX for update your data in your client coming from the Server (ASP.Net)

Comment: And how does that work? The OP already mentioned AJAX, so there is nothing to learn from your current answer...

Comment: is it make a hit to the server, when i refresh Javascript 1s time